# Animation Code Causing Unbearable Lag

Tags: java, animation, lwjgl

So, I've got this code for animating characters in LWJGL.  It is bringing a game that runs ~60 FPS to ~5 FPS.  Are there any changes I could make to fix it?  I heard caching was something to do, but I don't know how or if this is an actual solution

```
package geniushour.engine.animation;

import geniushour.engine.time.Delay;

public class Animator{

private Sprite spr;
private int frame;
private Delay delay;

public Animator(Sprite spr, int sheetLengthX, int sheetLengthY) {
    spr.setNum(sheetLengthX,sheetLengthY);
    this.spr = spr;
    frame = 0;
    delay = new Delay(500);
    delay.terminate();
}
public void animate2f(String sheet, int px1, int py1, int px2, int py2, int waitTime){
    spr.setTexture(sheet);
    if(delay.over() && frame == 0){
        spr.setPlace(px1,py1);
        frame++;
    }
    if(delay.over() && frame == 1){
        spr.setPlace(px2,py2);
        frame = 0;
    }
    delay.start();
}
public void animate4f(String sheet, int px1, int py1, int px2, int py2, int px3, int py3, int px4, int py4, int waitTime){
    spr.setTexture(sheet);
    if(delay.over() && frame == 0){
        spr.setPlace(px1,py1);
        frame++;
    }
    else if(delay.over() && frame == 1){
        spr.setPlace(px2,py2);
        frame++;
    }
    else if(delay.over() && frame == 2){
        spr.setPlace(px3,py3);
        frame++;
    }
    else if(delay.over() && frame == 3){
        spr.setPlace(px4,py4);
        frame = 0;
    }
    delay.start();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post the Sprite class also ? Is there a chance that you load the texture every time in the setTexture method ?

Comment: You have sparked an idea in me, thank you.  I believe I might be reloading the texture every fraction of a second, and that may be why it is causing lag.  I will try to fix this, and if it doesn't work I will post more info.